# Monodevelop,debuging DLL project which attachs to a process,

Tags: debugging, dll, monodevelop

I create a project,and I set "DLL" mode on output.  I want debug my dll project ,  so I do "attach to process",(at the beginning ,I can not find "attach to process",but after I install the "GUN debugger plugin monodevelop",I can find it in the RUN menu.)

I  debug a DLL project which has already attached to a process, but it always stop at the Line: `"b7799424  pop %ebp"`  in the `"Disassemly+"file`.

Application output shows:`"0Xb7799424in__kernel_vsyscall()"`.

I can not debug the DLL program.

```
 Anyone can give me some help to this trouble.
```

Demi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***The method of debugging the DLL (or library) project in Monodevelop IDE :***
      Instead of attaching to the exe that references your dll have MonoDevelop launch the exe for you. The trick to getting MonoDevelop to launch the exe for you is like this :

1. Create an empty solution.
2. Add your .exe project to this solution.
3. Continue to add your .dll project to the solution.
4. Set that your .exe project as the startup project.
5. Set the output path of your dll project in the debug file of your .exe project .
6. Build the entire solution and select Debug from the Run menu.

The  MonoDevelop will launch your exe in the debugger and should be able to break at breakpoints within your dll project.
     This methode is referenced by this [webpage](http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Debugging-mono-dll-loaded-by-Unity3d-td2291591.html).I tried this method and it can work.
     Hope this can help other people.
Demi

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the GDB debugger which is pretty low level, maybe you should try with the soft or hard debugger, [instructions are found on the monodevelop website](http://www.mono-project.com/Debugger)

Comment: I have aready installed the mono soft debugger library (for cli 4.0).      Before I installed the "GNU debugger plugin for monodevelop" in the software centre,I can not find "attach to process" in the "RUN" in monodevelop IDE .  Then after I installed it ,i meet this troublesome.